# Capture multiple jobs output with pgm=sdsf

Tags: mainframe, jcl, spool

I've built a job to retrieve information from spool executions (with the utility PGM=SDSF), but I can only seem to do that for one job at a time, by doing:

```
//SDSFS1   EXEC PGM=SDSF                                   
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                    
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                      
//ISFOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                      
//ISFIN DD *                                              
OWNER                                                     
PREFIX JOBXPTO
ST                                                        
FILTER MAX-RC EQ 'CC 0000'                                
FIND 'JOBXPTO'                                           
++?                                                       
RESET                                                     
FILTER PROCSTEP EQ 'FTPCMD'                               
FIND 'OUTPUT'                                             
++S                                                       
RESET                                                     
PRT ODSN 'WRKPX.SDSFS1' * SHR                      
PRT                                                       
PRT CLOSE                                                 
END
```

I can only get one ddname for one job at a time, what if I want to retrieve multiple DDNAMES from one job execution or
if I want tghe same DDNAME for multiple jobs in spool (cyclic jobs or just all jobs that have a FTPCMD)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're stretching past the limits of what can be reasonably done with SDSF commands in batch.  You need to loop through a variable number of jobs and neither JCL nor SDSF commands provide for that.

Please take a look at the [Rexx interface for SDSF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=guide-using-sdsf-rexx-programming-language).